# I am unable to install the latest version of the material ui

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui, icons, node-modules

I'm unable to install the material ui latest version , and I am getting an error in the terminal .

Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/utils/createSvgIcon.js 13:13-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/material/utils' in 'C:\Users\hrish\Desktop\tesla\tesla-clone\node_modules@mui\icons-material\utils'

I tried this:  npm install @mui/material@latest
npm install @mui/icons-material@latest